# Determine the value of c that makes the blue area above y = c equal to the blue area below y = c.

Tags: calculus, integration, area, curves

[image]

Determine the value of c that makes the blue area above y = c equal to the blue area below y = c.

edit: I'm kind of stuck on this problem, not sure what steps to do so that I can find the equal areas.
edit2: The answer looks right so far, thanks to everyone who helped out!

Comment: This should be routine exercise.  What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Do you know how to find where the line intersects the curve?  Do you know how to use integration to find the area?

Comment: Do you know how to find the average value of a function?

Comment: I've done the integral of f(x)-g(x), but I'm not sure where to begin for this problem. I don't see anything in the book that gives a clue as to how to figure out this particular question.

Comment: I'm not sure about intersection, I was thinking about doing the integral of the above function minus the y=c, but I don't see that going anywhere.

Comment: graphing the function on desmos, it seems the [a,b] is [0,.544]

Comment: f(x) is 8x-27x^3, g(x) is c (some constant I presume), doing the anti derivatives should lead to some more interesting numbers this is where I'm quite lost, and not sure what to do. The antiderivative of c could be anything, and the problem has lost me in its tracks.

Answer (score 3):

Some things to point out:

We take the integral of a function $f(x)$ to find the area under the curve. What we are essentially doing is finding the area $A=\int_a^b f(x)-0\quad\!\!\!dx$ which is the area under the function but above the $x$-axis.

So, the area of the left region would be $\int_0^a c-(8x-27x^3)dx$ and the area of the right region would be $\int_a^b 8x-27x^3-c\quad\!\!\!dx$, where $a$ and $b$ are the intersections of the two functions (when $8x-27x^3=c$).

But these areas have to be equal so the integrals so $\int_0^a c-(8x-27x^3)dx$=$\int_a^b 8x-27x^3-c\quad\!\!\!dx$

Comment: Hmm, I tried something similar. I can try this way.

Comment: I ended up with a = 4b^2 - (27/4)b^4, I graphed it on desmos, so I think b is 0.544 (the x-int for when y = 0) do I just plug this in for a? How can I test? I tried this and it looks definitely wrong on desmos.

Comment: zz20s's answer is correct.

Comment: I'm stuck on the plugging in part, can you clarify? edit: found my error, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=a$ be the first intersection and $x=b$ be the second.

The areas are equal, so $\displaystyle\int_0^a c-(8x-27x^3)dx=\int_a^b 8x-27x^3-cdx$. Carrying out the integration, we have:

$$cx-4x^2+\frac{27}{4}x^4\Bigg|_0^a= 4x^2-\frac{27}{4}x^4-cx\Bigg|_a^b$$

$$ca-4a^2+\frac{27}{4}a^4= 4b^2-\frac{27}{4}b^4-cb-4a^2+\frac{27}{4}a^4+ca$$

$$0= 4b^2-\frac{27}{4}b^4-cb=b(4b-\frac{27}{4}b^3-c)$$

Thus, $c=4b-\dfrac{27}{4}b^3$

Now, we also recall that $f(b)=8b-27b^3=c$

We set the two equations equal giving:

$$4b-\dfrac{27}{4}b^3=8b-27b^3$$

$$0=4b-\dfrac{81}{4}b^3$$

By normal methods, we find that $b=\dfrac{4}{9}$. We substitute this back into our equation relating $b$ and $c$ to find that: $$f(\dfrac{4}{9})=8\dfrac{4}{9}-27(\dfrac{4}{9})^3=\dfrac{32}{27}=c$$

Comment: I graphed the value of c along with the original function, it doesn't look quite right. Have you heard of desmos? My teacher showed it to the class and it has worked wonders. The c for this problem is far too high for the areas to be equal.

Comment: The vertex of the function is at around 1.67, and the c you gave was around 1.65. Therefore I don't think the answer that you provided can be correct, considering how close to the tip of the curve we are for this horizontal tangent line.

Comment: Ah, very beautiful, I will give this answer a shot.

Comment: Please tell me if anything is still incorrect!

Comment: I don't understand the substitution? 27(4/9)^3 is a very large number, how does that come out to 32/27?

Comment: $8\dfrac{4}{9}-27(\dfrac{4}{9})^3=\dfrac{32}{9}-27\dfrac{64}{729}=\dfrac{32}{9}-\dfrac{64}{27}$. Cubing a number less than $1$ gives a small number.

Comment: Made an easy mistake, thanks a bunch!